# What verb to use with the noun “groundbreaking”?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, word-usage

I need some help with the noun *groundbreaking*. According to the American Heritage Dictionary, 4th Edition, it is

> The act or ceremony of breaking ground to begin a construction project.

My question is, how do we use it? Do we say,

1. We performed the groundbreaking for the new hospital?
2. We did the groundbreaking for the new hospital?
3. We broke ground for the new hospital?

Or is there some other verb that we use for it?

Comment: You mean "some other **noun**" rather.

Comment: I do not know of any alternative nouns (synonyms) for *groundbreaking* although individual cultures have terms like *cutting, sod-cutting, turning the first sod* (Wikipedia). That said, even in standard English, it is usually followed by *ceremony*. The noun is very rare, so rare that some standard dictionaries do not list it as such. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundbreaking

Comment: @Kris, No. I meant verb, as in: (1) perform, (2) do, and (3) to break.

Comment: The title of your question is about how to use the noun. You conclude the body of your question asking about another verb. This is confusing and it's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: @JasonBassford Okay. I see the confusion now. I've edited the question title to make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Salam. We rarely use *groundbreaking* as a noun. You can check out [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/groundbreaking) for many examples of the verbs used with *groundbreaking* used as an adjective. Note: click on 'More Example Sentences'.